# How can I use gsub and grep to calculate the weighted average in R?

Tags: r, regex

I want to calculate the weighted average of different columns with different names. For example, weight4 is multiplied by 3, weight8 is multiplied by 2 and weight12 is multiply by 1, then we add all the numbers and divided by 6. This is an example, my real data has 53 variables, each one of them is measure in different timeframes denoted by the number at the end of the variables.
This is my dataset

```
weight4 <- c(4,2,3,4,5,6)
height4 <- c(4,2,3,3,5,8)
size4 <- c(2,3,5,6,2,3)
weight8 <- c(4,2,3,4,5,6)
height8 <- c(4,2,3,3,5,8)
size8 <- c(2,3,5,6,2,3)
weight12 <- c(4,2,3,4,5,6)
height12 <- c(4,2,3,3,5,8)
size12 <- c(2,3,5,6,2,3)
df <- data.frame(weight4, height4, size4, weight8, height8, size8,
                 weight12, height12, size12)
```

I want to calculate the weighted average of these columns: This is what I have so far

```
Z <- unique(gsub("\\..", "", grep("^\\[0-9]+$", names(df), value = TRUE)))
Z
new <- lapply(setNames(nm = Z), function(z) {
  Zs <- grep(paste0("^", z, "\\"), names(df))
  Zs_seq <- rev(seq_along(Zs))
  as.matrix(df[Zs]) %*% matrix(Zs_seq, ncol = 1) / sum(Zs_seq)
})
```

But it doesn't work for my data. Any Idea on how I can change this function for my data?

This line of code works for each variable:

```
weight <- grep("weight", names(df))
Xs_seq <- rev(seq_along(weight))
weight <- as.matrix(df[weight]) %*% matrix(Xs_seq, ncol = 1) / sum(Xs_seq)
df$weight <- weight
```

I would like to know if there is a way in which I can make R looks for the pattern in the data without having to manually use each variable in the data frame

Comment: grep/gsub feels hacky. FWIW I would probably try to (1) melt/pivot to a long format; (2) separate type identifier (size/height/weight) and value (this step would take some regex machinery); (3) multiply/group by/average. (I'm still unclear on exactly what/how you want to calculate, I haven't taken the time to understand your code ... a much simpler example might help me ...)

Comment: I'm also a little unclear on what you're attempting to do here. Are you trying to calculate the weighted average of the "heights", "weights", and "sizes" by assigning a different weight to the 4, 8, and 12? You could calculate a simple weighted average for each column using `apply` instead: `apply(df, 2, FUN = weighted.mean, w=weights)`, where weights is a vector of how much to weight each row.

Comment: I want to calculate the weighted mean by sequence, in this case weight4 is multiply by 3, weight8 is multiply by 2, and weight12 is multiplied by 1, I add all the numbers and then divided by 6. I am doing this because I have 53 each variable has a match of the same variable but with the number I use as example, that is why I want to recognize the pattern. This code works for each variable  ```g100125 <- grep("weight", names(df))
Xs_seq <- rev(seq_along(weight))
weight <- as.matrix(df[weight]) %*% matrix(Xs_seq, ncol = 1) / sum(Xs_seq)
df$weight <- weight
```

Comment: 1) How do you decide to multiply `weight4` by 3, `weight8` by 2 and `weight12` by 1. Is there some logic involved or this is hardcoded? 2) Most importantly, can you show the expected output for example shared?

Comment: Base on the number of times this is repeated. That's why I use ```seq_along(weight)``` If I had four weights I multiply by 4, 3, 2, 1. The code does give the expected output, what I cannot do is make R identify the recurrent names of the variables and do this in one single step without manually inserting all the variables.